# In office ui fabric how can I get default selected value on button click

Tags: office-ui-fabric

In my application I used office ui fabric react drop down control, when I click on button I need to check it's empty or not?

```
public options = [
    { key: 'Employee Name', text: 'Employee Name' },
    { key: 'Employee ID', text: 'Employee ID' },
    { key: 'Department', text: 'Department' }
];

<Dropdown defaultSelectedKey="Employee Name" options={this.options} onChange={this._onChange} />
<input type="button" value="Get Data" id="btnSub" onClick={() => this.readItem()} />


private readItem(): void {
    what I need to do here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

read the value from the event target.

`(e) => this.readItem(e.value.target)`

Comment: I need validation for dropdown on button click. As for your solution I will get only button data not dropdown. Note: Without implementing the onchange event on dropdown

Comment: @brahmareddy okay, your question wasn't clear then. What are you trying to check? That the input is empty -- like your original question? Or that you have data in a dropdown? I'm confused as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ ehutchllew okay, I have one dropdown in my application. In this dropdown I have three options (Values of three options are option1, option2 and option3). I set option1 as the default selected value. Also I have one button, when I click on button I need to get dropdown selected value(it means output value is option1 ). Note: Here I am not change the dropdown selected value, so onchange event will not fire. Without onchange event how can I get dropdown selected value.

Comment: @brahmareddy I guess it depends on the structure of your code. Generally you should let React handle the state for you, so you should associate a state variable with your Dropdown values, then this would be easy for your button to just grab whatever the current selected state value is.